# Typescript TS2322 Error on Generic Interface Method "could be instantiated with a different subtype"

Tags: typescript, generics, interface

How would I write this interface **method** correctly so that it can be generic. Note that I do not want to make entire interface generic and `T` could be `Record<string, string>` or another interface that *extends* `Record<string, string>`.  Minimal example below.

```js
interface IFoo {
    source: <T extends Record<string, string>>(table: string, calcEngine?: string, tab?: string, predicate?: (row: T) => boolean) => Array<T>;
}

const getFooRows = function <T extends Record<string, string>>(table: string, calcEngine?: string, tab?: string) {
    var row1: Record<string, string> = {};
    var row2: Record<string, string> = {};
    return [row1, row2] as Array<T>;
}

const bar: IFoo = {
    source(table, calcEngine, tab, predicate) {
        return predicate
            ? getFooRows(table, calcEngine, tab).filter(r => predicate!(r))
            : getFooRows(table, calcEngine, tab);
    }
}
```

With this code, I'm hoping to do something like the following:

```js
interface ICustomRow extends Record<string, string> {
    customProp1: string;
    customProp2: string;
}

const genericRows = bar.source("genericTable");
genericRows.forEach( r => {
    // r is just Record<string, string>, no intellisene on r
    console.log(`${r["dynamicProp1"]} ${r["dynamicProp2"]}`);
});

const customRows = bar.source<ICustomRow>("customTable");
customRows.forEach( r => {
    // r should be a ICustomRow
    // Intellisense should should 'customProp1/2' when I type 'r.'
    // Should also be able to access r["dynamicProp1"] without compile error as well
    console.log(`${r.customProp1} ${r.customProp2}`);
});
```

I understand that a caller could pass in a type for `T` that doesn't correspond to the data held in the table identified by `table`, but that will be documented as a requirement.  This is mostly for 'internal' calling inside my entire typescript project to save me from always doing a `.source() as Array<ICustomRow>`, it is just a preference to do `.source<ICustomRow>()`.  It reads better 'to me'.

However, with this code, I get following compile error:

> Error TS2322  (TS)
>
> Type '<T extends Record<string, string>>(table: string, calcEngine: string | undefined, tab: string | undefined, predicate: ((row: T) => boolean) | undefined) => Record<string, string>[]' is not assignable to type '<T extends Record<string, string>>(table: string, calcEngine?: string | undefined, tab?: string | undefined, predicate?: ((row: T) => boolean) | undefined) => T[]'.
>
> Type 'Record<string, string>[]' is not assignable to type 'T[]'.
>
> Type 'Record<string, string>' is not assignable to type 'T'.
>
> 'Record<string, string>' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Record<string, string>'.

Comment: Given your example code, I'd just explicitly annotate and specify your types so the compiler can follow it, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NnbeqN).  But note that `getFooRows()` is impossible to implement safely, since it claims to return `T[]` for any `T` the caller specifies, even though none of the parameters to that function have anything to do with `T`.

Comment: I guess that's out of scope for the question as asked, but I'd feel more comfortable if you could [edit] the question to demonstrate how you expect this to be used.  Is it really true that `bar.source<string>("abc")` could produce a `string[]` and `bar.source<number>("abc")` could produce a `number[]`?  How does that work?  Is it just that you expect callers to be careful with their TS types?

Comment: Anyway let me know if [this](https://tsplay.dev/NnbeqN) meets your needs; if so I could write up an answer.  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Updated my question to show desired usage.  So it looks like all you did in your playground is explicitly declare the function type again?  It can't be implied from the interface?

Comment: The important part is specifying the type parameter on the inner call to `getFooRows()` like `getFooRows<T>(...)`, but you don't have a name for the type `T` unless you actually declare it.  You *could* do [this](https://tsplay.dev/WkkOPW) instead, to have another handle on the type `T`, but it's cleaner to just properly annotate your function.

Comment: But the reason all of this is happening is the inherent lack of safety of your methods and the fact that it is not feasible to infer `T` from a call to a function whose function parameters don't depend on `T`.  Your intended usage is to call `bar.source<ICustomRow>("customTable")`, but that's not safe.  Nothing stops a caller from calling `bar.source<SomeRandomType)("customTable")` and then runtime errors are likely.  Do you understand this?  If so, can you mention that in the question that you understand the risks and don't care?  If not, I guess I need to explain more

Comment: I like the last implementation.  Both actually work.  If you could answer with the second one and explain the black magic going on with `type T = Parameters<NonNullable<typeof predicate>>[0];` I'd be grateful.  Thanks!

Comment: Updated, stating I understand and the reason behind the desired interface and call mechanics.

Comment: "to save me from always doing a `.source() as Array<ICustomRow>`" is fine, but "I understand that a caller could pass in a type for `T` that doesn't extend `Record<string, string`" is missing the issue.  Someone could pass a `T` that does extend `Record<string, string>` but not one appropriate to the table name, like [this shows](https://tsplay.dev/Wy6lJw).  Anyway I'll work on writing up the answer but maybe you could fix up that part a bit in the meantime?

Comment: "to save me from always doing a `.source() as Array<ICustomRow>`" is fine, but "I understand that a caller could pass in a type for `T` that doesn't extend `Record<string, string`" is missing the issue.  Someone could pass a `T` that does extend `Record<string, string>` but not one appropriate to the table name, like [this shows](https://tsplay.dev/Wy6lJw).  Anyway I'll work on writing up the answer but maybe you could fix up that part a bit in the meantime?

Comment: I'm going to make that edit to your question now; hope you don't mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `getFooRows()` is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in a type parameter `T` but none of the parameters in its call signature actually depend on that type parameter, so the compiler fails to infer that it's the same `T` as the one for your `source()`.  (This is indicative of a type safety issue, but as you mention in the question that you're aware of it, I won't belabor the point here.)

The way to deal with this is to get a hold of the generic type parameter `T` from the `source()` call signature in the object literal, and explicitly specify it in the calls to `getFooRows()`.  Unfortunately, because you haven't [annotated the method parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#parameter-type-annotations) and are relying on [contextual typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing), you don't have a name for that type in scope.

We *could* decide to explicitly annotate everything like this:

```
const bar: IFoo = {
    source<T extends Record<string, string>>(
        table: string, calcEngine?: string, 
        tab?: string, predicate?: (row: T) => boolean
    ) {
        return predicate
            ? getFooRows<T>(table, calcEngine, tab).filter(r => predicate(r))
            : getFooRows<T>(table, calcEngine, tab);
    }
}
```

That compiles fine, but let's see how we can avoid this.

---

If you had a parameter `t` of type `T`, you could write `typeof t`.  But you don't.  In fact, the only parameter you have even somewhat related to `T` is `predicate`, which is of type `((row: T) => boolean) | undefined`.  (Note that this is an optional parameter, meaning it's easy to call `source()` without any argument that depends on `T`.  This is, again, indicative of a type safety issue.  And again, you know this, and I won't go on about it other than to make this parenthetical disclaimer.)

So, to extract `T` from `typeof predicate`, first we have to get rid of that union with `undefined`. There's a provided [`NonNullable<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) which removes `null` and `undefined` from unions, so we can start with `NonNullable<typeof predicate>`, which is then `(row: T) => boolean`.

Now we have a function type whose parameter is what we want.  There's a provided [`Parameters<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) that gets the [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of the list of parameter types for a function.  So we can use `Parameters<NonNullable<typeof predicate>>`, which is `[row: T]`.

Finally we have a tuple one one element, and we want that element type.  We can grab that by [indexing into it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) with the index `0`, to get `T`.  That gives us:

```
const bar: IFoo = {
    source(table, calcEngine?, tab?, predicate?) {
        type T = Parameters<NonNullable<typeof predicate>>[0]
        return predicate
            ? getFooRows<T>(table, calcEngine, tab).filter(r => predicate(r))
            : getFooRows<T>(table, calcEngine, tab);
    }
}
```

This also compiles fine.

Note that we don't have to use utility types; instead we can use [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to pull the relevant type out more directly, like this:

```
const bar: IFoo = {
    source(table, calcEngine?, tab?, predicate?) {
        type T = typeof predicate extends 
          ((row: infer T) => boolean) | undefined ? T : never;
        return predicate
            ? getFooRows<T>(table, calcEngine, tab).filter(r => predicate(r))
            : getFooRows<T>(table, calcEngine, tab);
    }
}
```

Which also works.

---

So there you go, three ways to get a handle on the type `T` to pass in to fix the error.  Oh, and four, if you want to just acknowledge that there's no type safety guarantees here, you might as well just pass in [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) and move on:

```
const bar: IFoo = {
    source(table, calcEngine?, tab?, predicate?) {
        return predicate
            ? getFooRows<any>(table, calcEngine, tab).filter(r => predicate(r))
            : getFooRows<any>(table, calcEngine, tab);
    }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8&ts=4.8.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDED2nkG8CwAUMicgM6YCuUSAXMgDwAqyEAHpCACZnIBKEBJihcGZMFFABzADTkJ0gHyKAFGDgAjADYR64ySFnIEcLQgCih0BAD8ehYbnqNd+QaMAHKBC7ATkVxUoTAB3eiYASmQAXkVkDWwdOBAo2OQAQSgoOABPZkUAbiIAXyIiIRBxZCkIMCxMPlDeaOQYShAEMGBMEEYWdk4efkFhUX1pOXHDZTVNHXt3ORMzSylrVymjZw2HKSiCYlIANzgoZGCQgEZ6ASERMV3J3biW3GKiw5ITs4uAJhuRvdNk93C88O8iKRzrVqL0ANoXS5yP4AXWQcF4mWyeSYhRKZUIFSqGlOAFlchpdGh6jE8JDSBRqEhmKwOBBuLxbqMHos3EpVPSoSRnPM+Y5jKYLFYQLYFhNkNs5eKvD4-HAAvQgqFwqk4glMEkQILkPtjVDvGBYcgVb5-BAzUKSDZqrV6o0QmR8rNtBAlpLVtYnJoIgA6GDALSQKBBGJxG1qyBBCIRB2O+g1OrYd2e3HenR+lbS30K4MfKGlQgV8o9YmnegYbC0g5Qxk0CB54vLKVrGU2IMuOTxu02U2fIVgHIeFAsFoABVOcAAtrVoJ6AHI9NeULRaOYQBgTqeYGDW7y29UQZRwgAMKNT0MtUF6Q4v96hzozbqaXpFnf9Rf7UNw0jaAYzSF9EygZM31IdNXSzb9c1-Atu0DEsNAiMtSArKtCAJIkwHiU50i0Ch6xpV5jVbJAOxQgNe37PtT1VYdR0dYVJ2nWlDwgY9mPPSBWUGXgVC1MJkFAGBoGQSJY3iRIIGSKIAB9kHaLgIHDGUuGQZ0WHoGUjmgLDHQtK0IPtMd2N0l1MwaRDVGQiVCx7YtnCAiMozAuMzwTdsoJTKz2Lguzsx-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)